# lime cannot build the html5 target, compliling results in various type and import errors

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I am reviving an older haxeflixel project of mine and have been unable to get it to compile using lime.

To make sure it wasn't an issue with my code I created a new "hello world" project with `flixel tpl -n "HelloWorld"`.

I made sure the most recent version of haxe was installed, ran `haxelib update` as well as `haxelib run lime setup`

I'm using Windows 10.

All packages say they are up to date. Stack Overflow will not let me enter the entire error log, it's over 60,000 characters! I've posted a representative sample.

```
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/_internal/graphics/ImageDataUtil.hx:955: characters 32-67 : Class<lime._internal.backend.native.NativeCFFI> has no field lime_image_data_util_multiply_alpha
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/_internal/graphics/ImageDataUtil.hx:1405: characters 32-69 : Class<lime._internal.backend.native.NativeCFFI> has no field lime_image_data_util_unmultiply_alpha
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/_internal/graphics/ImageDataUtil.hx:1106: characters 32-63 : Class<lime._internal.backend.native.NativeCFFI> has no field lime_image_data_util_set_format
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/cairo/Cairo.hx:747: characters 14-38 : Class<lime._internal.backend.native.NativeCFFI> has no field lime_cairo_set_tolerance
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/cairo/Cairo.hx:738: characters 21-45 : Class<lime._internal.backend.native.NativeCFFI> has no field lime_cairo_get_tolerance
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/cairo/Cairo.hx:729: characters 21-42 : Class<lime._internal.backend.native.NativeCFFI> has no field lime_cairo_get_target
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/cairo/Cairo.hx:720: characters 14-35 : Class<lime._internal.backend.native.NativeCFFI> has no field lime_cairo_set_source
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/cairo/Cairo.hx:711: characters 21-42 : Class<lime._internal.backend.native.NativeCFFI> has no field lime_cairo_get_source

etc. etc.

C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/8,9,6/src/openfl/_internal/renderer/cairo/CairoTextField.hx:246: characters 21-28 : Float has no field advance
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/8,9,6/src/openfl/_internal/renderer/cairo/CairoTextField.hx:327: characters 63-78 : Float should be Int
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/8,9,6/src/openfl/_internal/renderer/cairo/CairoTextField.hx:327: characters 63-78 : For function argument ''
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/ui/Gamepad.hx:41: characters 14-39 : Class<lime._internal.backend.native.NativeCFFI> has no field lime_gamepad_add_mappings
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/utils/Bytes.hx:133: characters 21-49 : Class<lime._internal.backend.native.NativeCFFI> has no field lime_bytes_from_data_pointer
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check your environment variables (you can just type `set` into a terminal to see all of them). There is an issue where Lime thinks it's compiling for native if `hl` is defined, resulting in classes like `NativeCFFI` being included, even though they normally have no business being used on HTML5.

If you don't have `hl` defined, there may still be another environment variable that triggers the same problem.

Comment: I removed the ```hl``` env variable and almost all the errors are gone!

 I am still getting this one though:

```C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/8,9,6/src/openfl/display/Stage.hx:1426: characters 46-59 : haxe.CallStack has no field lastException```

Comment: That's unrelated. The latest OpenFL release is currently not compatible with the latest Haxe release on the HTML5 target, either update to OpenFL from GitHub or downgrade to Haxe 4.0.x.