# Lime fails to build to html5. Compiling gives many errors that I do not know how to fix

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

Sorry if this is poorly formatted I am new to discussion threads.

I am following the directions to make a hello world with HaxeFixel and lime listed [here.](https://haxeflixel.com/documentation/hello-world/)

When I attempt to build to html5 I get these errors. I made sure the haxe, flixel, and lime were all up to date.

I am on Windows 10

There was similiar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62368938/lime-cannot-build-the-html5-target-compliling-results-in-various-type-and-impor) that described a similar issue but I have no system variable defined with the name hl and I am unsure of any other ones that could be causing an issue.

These are the errors.

```
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/_internal/backend/html5/HTML5Window.hx:321: characters 5-26 : lime._internal.backend.html5.HTML5WebGL2RenderContext should be lime.graphics.WebGLRenderContext
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/flixel/4,8,1/flixel/group/FlxGroup.hx:473: characters 80-91 : Type not found : ObjectClass
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 3-18 : Could not find a suitable overload, reasons follow
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 3-18 : Overload resolution failed for (array : Array<Float>, ?offset : Null<Int>) -> Void
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : lime.math.ColorMatrix should be Array<Float>
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : ... For function argument 'array'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 3-18 : Overload resolution failed for (array : js.lib.Int8Array, ?offset : Null<Int>) -> Void
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : lime.math.ColorMatrix should be js.lib.Int8Array
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : ... For function argument 'array'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 3-18 : Overload resolution failed for (array : js.lib.Uint8Array, ?offset : Null<Int>) -> Void
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : lime.math.ColorMatrix should be js.lib.Uint8Array
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : ... For function argument 'array'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 3-18 : Overload resolution failed for (array : js.lib.Uint8ClampedArray, ?offset : Null<Int>) -> Void
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : lime.math.ColorMatrix should be js.lib.Uint8ClampedArray
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : ... For function argument 'array'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 3-18 : Overload resolution failed for (array : js.lib.Int16Array, ?offset : Null<Int>) -> Void
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : lime.math.ColorMatrix should be js.lib.Int16Array
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : ... For function argument 'array'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 3-18 : Overload resolution failed for (array : js.lib.Uint16Array, ?offset : Null<Int>) -> Void
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : lime.math.ColorMatrix should be js.lib.Uint16Array
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : ... For function argument 'array'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 3-18 : Overload resolution failed for (array : js.lib.Int32Array, ?offset : Null<Int>) -> Void
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : lime.math.ColorMatrix should be js.lib.Int32Array
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : ... For function argument 'array'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 3-18 : Overload resolution failed for (array : js.lib.Uint32Array, ?offset : Null<Int>) -> Void
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : lime.math.ColorMatrix should be js.lib.Uint32Array
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : ... For function argument 'array'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 3-18 : Overload resolution failed for (array : js.lib.Float32Array, ?offset : Null<Int>) -> Void
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : lime.math.ColorMatrix should be js.lib.Float32Array
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : ... For function argument 'array'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 3-18 : Overload resolution failed for (array : js.lib.Float64Array, ?offset : Null<Int>) -> Void
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : lime.math.ColorMatrix should be js.lib.Float64Array
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : ... For function argument 'array'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 3-18 : Overload resolution failed for (array : Array<Int>, ?offset : Null<Int>) -> Void
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : lime.math.ColorMatrix should be Array<Int>
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : ... For function argument 'array'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 3-18 : End of overload failure reasons
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/utils/src/openfl/utils/ByteArray.hx:750: characters 3-30 : openfl.utils.ByteArray should be lime.utils._Bytes.LimeBytes
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/stage3d/src/openfl/display3D/VertexBuffer3D.hx:113: characters 41-45 : openfl.utils.ByteArray should be Null<Int>
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/stage3d/src/openfl/display3D/VertexBuffer3D.hx:113: characters 41-45 : ... For optional function argument 'elements'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/stage3d/src/openfl/display3D/VertexBuffer3D.hx:113: characters 41-45 : ... For function argument 'data'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 3-18 : Could not find a suitable overload, reasons follow
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 3-18 : Overload resolution failed for (array : Array<Float>, ?offset : Null<Int>) -> Void
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : lime.math.Matrix4 should be Array<Float>
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : ... For function argument 'array'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 3-18 : Overload resolution failed for (array : js.lib.Int8Array, ?offset : Null<Int>) -> Void
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : lime.math.Matrix4 should be js.lib.Int8Array
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : ... For function argument 'array'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 3-18 : Overload resolution failed for (array : js.lib.Uint8Array, ?offset : Null<Int>) -> Void
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : lime.math.Matrix4 should be js.lib.Uint8Array
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : ... For function argument 'array'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 3-18 : Overload resolution failed for (array : js.lib.Uint8ClampedArray, ?offset : Null<Int>) -> Void
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : lime.math.Matrix4 should be js.lib.Uint8ClampedArray
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : ... For function argument 'array'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 3-18 : Overload resolution failed for (array : js.lib.Int16Array, ?offset : Null<Int>) -> Void
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : lime.math.Matrix4 should be js.lib.Int16Array
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : ... For function argument 'array'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 3-18 : Overload resolution failed for (array : js.lib.Uint16Array, ?offset : Null<Int>) -> Void
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : lime.math.Matrix4 should be js.lib.Uint16Array
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : ... For function argument 'array'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 3-18 : Overload resolution failed for (array : js.lib.Int32Array, ?offset : Null<Int>) -> Void
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : lime.math.Matrix4 should be js.lib.Int32Array
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : ... For function argument 'array'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 3-18 : Overload resolution failed for (array : js.lib.Uint32Array, ?offset : Null<Int>) -> Void
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : lime.math.Matrix4 should be js.lib.Uint32Array
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : ... For function argument 'array'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 3-18 : Overload resolution failed for (array : js.lib.Float32Array, ?offset : Null<Int>) -> Void
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : lime.math.Matrix4 should be js.lib.Float32Array
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : ... For function argument 'array'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 3-18 : Overload resolution failed for (array : js.lib.Float64Array, ?offset : Null<Int>) -> Void
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : lime.math.Matrix4 should be js.lib.Float64Array
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : ... For function argument 'array'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 3-18 : Overload resolution failed for (array : Array<Int>, ?offset : Null<Int>) -> Void
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : lime.math.Matrix4 should be Array<Int>
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : ... For function argument 'array'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 3-18 : End of overload failure reasons
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/media/openal/AL.hx:1307: characters 3-11 : Int should be lime.media.openal.ALBuffer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,8,0/src/lime/media/OpenALAudioContext.hx:573: characters 3-40 : lime.media.openal.ALBuffer should be Int
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/sound/src/openfl/media/Sound.hx:591: characters 37-42 : openfl.utils.ByteArray should be Null<Int>
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/sound/src/openfl/media/Sound.hx:591: characters 37-42 : ... For optional function argument 'elements'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/flixel/4,8,1/flixel/group/FlxGroup.hx:852: characters 19-30 : Type not found : ObjectClass
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/flixel/4,8,1/flixel/system/frontEnds/PluginFrontEnd.hx:47: characters 19-28 : Type not found : ClassType
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/flixel/4,8,1/flixel/system/frontEnds/PluginFrontEnd.hx:94: characters 20-29 : Type not found : ClassType
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/bitmapdata/src/openfl/display/BitmapData.hx:1885: characters 45-54 : openfl.utils.ByteArray should be lime.utils.BytePointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/bitmapdata/src/openfl/display/BitmapData.hx:1885: characters 45-54 : ... For function argument 'bytePointer'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/assets/src/openfl/utils/AssetLibrary.hx:47: characters 52-57 : openfl.utils.ByteArray should be lime.utils.Bytes
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/assets/src/openfl/utils/AssetLibrary.hx:47: characters 52-57 : ... For function argument 'bytes'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/assets/src/openfl/utils/AssetLibrary.hx:293: characters 38-43 : openfl.utils.ByteArray should be lime.utils.Bytes
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/assets/src/openfl/utils/AssetLibrary.hx:293: characters 38-43 : ... For function argument 'bytes'
```

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** OpenFL 9.1.0 and Lime 7.9.0 are available by now, and compatible with Haxe 4.2.x.

---

It looks like you have installed the latest Haxe release 4.2.0. You need to downgrade it to 4.1.5 or lower for now, as the current Haxelib releases of OpenFL (9.0.2) and Lime (7.8.0) don't support 4.2.0 yet.

On Windows, you can simply run the [4.1.5 installer](https://haxe.org/download/version/4.1.5/) over the previous installation.